# Open link in new tab but without _blank method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I have somewhere read that using `<a href="#" target="_blank">URL</a>` can be easy to hack, specifically, using the `target="_blank"` method can be risky because some javascript can be triggered after clicking on link with `"target="_blank"`

Is there any other way to open link in new tab?
Thank you so much, I appreciate it.

Comment: even if you don't want to use it , the html is a client side and user can edit the html and add that target into any element he/she want , so there is no use of saying i don't want to use it.

Comment: You haven't understood me.

Answer (score 0):

```
function UserNewTab(url) {
  var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
   }
```

`<a onclick="UserNewTab();">Click Here</a>`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
    window.open(url, '_blank');
});
```